# Display Tick Mark instead of "0" or "1"

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I currently have a page pulling info from a database. Right now, the value of a field is displayed as 0 (no) or 1 (yes). Instead of displaying 0 or 1, I'd like to display ☐ (no) or ☑ (yes) instead. I'd think this would be simply, but my brain just isn't comprehending the right way to work it.

Here's my code.

```
<li>
    <p class='ui-li-lbl'>
        <span class='ui-li-val'>
            <%= model.get('leadcontacted_c') %>
        </span>
    &nbsp;Contacted By Corporate
    </p>
</li>
```

Comment: You mean you need a checkbox input?

Comment: @j08691 - LOL! if that's really it.. I don't know if it's funny or sad

Comment: @j08691 I'm not necessarily looking for an input field on a form. There is no form on my page, rather it spits out info about a particular record in my db. Imagine my question asked how to display img1.png if the value of my field (leadcontacted_c) is "0" or display "img2.png" if the value of the database feild is "1".

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like

```
<li>
    <p class='ui-li-lbl'>
        <span class='ui-li-val'>
        <input type="checkbox" name="myCheckbox" value="contacted"
```

<%= (model.get('leadcontacted_c') == 1 ? 'checked' : '') %> >
            
         Contacted By Corporate

this methodology you are using mixes html output with your code. Use this feature to render a checkbox and conditionally render the checked attribute

Answer (score 0):

```
<li>
    <p class='ui-li-lbl'>
        <span class='ui-li-val'>
            <input type="checkbox" <%= iif(model.get('leadcontacted_c') = 1,"checked","") %> />
        </span>
    &nbsp;Contacted By Corporate
    </p>
</li>
```